# Should the webpack modules object have holes in it?

Tags: webpack, webpack-2

Since I'm not using the DedupePlugin, nor the UglifyPlugin, I would have thought the modules object would not be fragmented like this, but in my webpack 2 setup, several of the "modules" are missing:

[image: Note that 3 is missing as well as 7-46]

Is this normal?

The problem I'm seeing is:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'call' of undefined(…)
```

which is caused by various plugins/configs, (none of which I'm doing at the moment)  This code was working prior to upgrading to from webpack-1.13.3 to webpack-2.1.0-beta27